# Typescript what is "this" in property decorator implementation?

Tags: typescript, decorator

I am learning TypeScript decorators but having trouble finding good examples of property decorators implementation. The only example I found are using following constructs: `var _val = this[key];` and `if(delete this[key])`. As I understand "this" in this case is javascript "global" object. Why would we look for property in the global object and try to delete it?

Comment: Are you referring to this article? http://blog.wolksoftware.com/decorators-metadata-reflection-in-typescript-from-novice-to-expert-part-ii

Comment: It is one of the examples I found, couple of others also referenced 'this[key]'